# If both the sum and sum of squares of two rationals are integers, the two rationals are integers too

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are two rational numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha + \beta,\ \alpha^2 + \beta^2$ are both integers. Prove that $\alpha, \beta$ are integers.

I started off by assuming that $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}, \beta = \frac{c}{d}$ such that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(c, d) = 1$ and $b, d \neq 1$.

$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}$ is an integer. Let $\frac{a}{b} - \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor = x , \frac{c}{d} - \lfloor\frac{c}{d}\rfloor = y$

$\implies x + y = 1$ and $\left(\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor+x\right)\left(\lfloor\frac{c}{d}\rfloor+y\right)$ is an integer

$\implies \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor \lfloor\frac{c}{d}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor y + \lfloor\frac{c}{d}\rfloor x + xy$ is also an integer

Since the leading term is an integer, the rest must be an integer too. Substituting $y = 1-x$ we get

$\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor - \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor x + \lfloor\frac{c}{d}\rfloor x + x - x^2$

Again, the leading term is an integer, so we can remove it. Simplifying the rest, we get...

$x\left(\lfloor\frac{c}{d}\rfloor - \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor + 1 - x\right)$ is an integer.

I couldn't think of any other suitable transformation and couldn't hit a contradiction.

I would prefer a solution that elaborates on what I have done above.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\alpha + \beta$ is an integer, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same denominator; i.e. $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$, $\beta = \frac{c}{b}$, in reduced form.

Then $2\alpha\beta = (\alpha + \beta)^2 - (\alpha^2 + \beta^2)$ is an integer, so $\frac{2ac}{b^2}$ is an integer.  This means $b^2 \;\big| \; 2$, which means $b = 1$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers.

Comment: I don't understand how you state that $\alpha, \beta$ will have the same denominator in their reduced state.

Comment: @Gerard First multiply the relation $a/c+b/d=n$ until the two denominators are coprime $>1$. Then multiply by both denominators, and reduce the equation modulo one of the denominators to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Actually you can just take $a/b + c/d = n$ and multiply by the lesser of $b$ and $d$.  Then (say if $b \le d$), we have $a + cb/d = bn$, hence $d | b$, hence $b = d$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\alpha+\beta=k$ and $\alpha=\dfrac{a}{b}$, then $\alpha^2+(k-\alpha)^2-k^2=2\alpha^2-2\alpha k=\dfrac{2a}{b}\left(\dfrac{a}{b}-k\right)$ must be integer.